# How to get and show a value from an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to get and show a value obtained with an Asynctask but i'm not very familiar with it...

My AsyncTask :

```
private class loadDetails extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            final Movie details = (Movie) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("MOVIE_DETAILS");
            int idMovie = details.getId();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + idMovie + "?api_key=" + API_KEY + "&language=en-US")
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

            int runtime = root.getInt("runtime");
            Log.i("test", runtime + " min");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //?
        }
    }
```

My full activity code :

```
public class MovieDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView backdrop_image, poster;
    private TextView overview, releaseDate, genresList;
    private RatingBar rating;
    private static final String TAG = "MovieDetails";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail);
        new loadDetails().execute();

        final Movie details = (Movie) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("MOVIE_DETAILS");

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(details.getTitle());

        backdrop_image = findViewById(R.id.movie_backdrop_image);
        poster = findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
        title = findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
        releaseDate = findViewById(R.id.movie_release_date);
        rating = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.movie_rating_bar);
        overview = findViewById(R.id.movie_overview);
        genresList = findViewById(R.id.movie_genres);

        if (details != null){

            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(IMAGE_BASE_URL + details.getBackdropPath())
                    .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .into(backdrop_image);
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(IMAGE_BASE_URL + details.getPosterPath())
                    .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .into(poster);

            title.setText(details.getTitle());
            releaseDate.setText(details.getReleaseDate());
            overview.setText(details.getOverview());
            double d = details.getTMDBRating();
            float f = (float) d;
            rating.setRating(f/2);

        }
    }

    private class loadDetails extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            final Movie details = (Movie) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("MOVIE_DETAILS");
            int idMovie = details.getId();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + idMovie + "?api_key=" + API_KEY + "&language=en-US")
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

            int runtime = root.getInt("runtime");
            Log.i("test", runtime + " min");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //?
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.save_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to display the `runtime` in a TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private class loadDetails extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer>() {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        final Movie details = (Movie) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("MOVIE_DETAILS");
        int idMovie = details.getId();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + idMovie + "?api_key=" + API_KEY + "&language=en-US")
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

        int runtime = root.getInt("runtime");
        Log.i("test", runtime + " min");

        return runtime;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer anInt) {
        yourTextView.setText("yourInt = " + anInt);
    }
}
```

that should do the trick.. I didn't compile it but generally the 3rd generics parameter of the async task is the return type from `doInBackround()` to `onPostExecute()` and there you can touch your views.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
//create a method to set the value to the textview
private void setTextViewValue(int runtime)
{
     textView.setText(String.valueOf(runtime))
}
//change the last parameter to Integer
private class loadDetails extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer>() {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            final Movie details = (Movie) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("MOVIE_DETAILS");
            int idMovie = details.getId();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + idMovie + "?api_key=" + API_KEY + "&language=en-US")
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

            int runtime = root.getInt("runtime");
            Log.i("test", runtime + " min");

            return runtime;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer runtime) {
            //call the method to set the runtime value
            setTextViewValue(runtime);
        }
    }
```

To simply explain it AsyncTask parameters are as follows:

- 1st parameter - datatype of value passed to execute() function and gets received by doInBackground()
- 2nd parameter - datatype of value passed to onProgressUpdate()
- 3rd paramater is datatype of value returned by doInBackground and passed to onPostExecute() when it is invoked

OnPostExecute will then call your custom function to set text to textview.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is not lifecycle aware, meaning if the user changes configuration, your app will leak memory; it might even crash. Thus you need to use [Livedata](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel.html), which will only update your activity when the activity is active. If your app crashes you will lose customers and it's considered bad programming practice in the industry.